# Determine the frequency and on time of two coupled ne555

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, frequency, math, 555

I've the following circuit:

[image]

I use it as a voltage controlled pwm generator. My question is, how can I find the frequency and on time of the PWM. I tried changing all the resistor and capacitor values and they all change te frequency so what is the relation?

I thought maybe I could use:

$$\text{f}=\frac{1.44}{\text{C}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}_1+2\cdot\text{R}_2}=\frac{1.44}{9\cdot10^{-9}}\cdot\frac{1}{20\cdot1000+2\cdot537}=7592.29\tag1$$

So that is not true :(

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: 555 application circuits and calculations are one of the most plentifully-documented areas in electronics. I'm sure you could have found all this in great detail on the internet yourself. Voting to close I'm afraid, no effort demonstrated.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks for the tips. I edited the things into the question that I tried.

Comment: @TonyM I did not find documentation about the circuit I described.

Comment: Without any symbols, that formula is not worth very much, unfortunately.

Comment: @MrGerber See my edit.

Comment: What software you are using to simulate

Comment: where did you find this circuit? out1 triggers slower out2 to become a frequency divider N= fout1/out2  =4?

Comment: i.e. a sub-harmonic lock generator